# Как правильно реализовать асинхронное общение с оборудованием?

Tags: c#, асинхронность, tpl, io

У меня есть оборудование подключенное к ПК через последовательный порт. Для работы с ним я использую объект `Stream` от `SerialPort.BaseStream`. Так что логика взаимодействия будет идентична всему, что работает через `Stream`.
Есть два способа общения с устройством:

1. Общение в стиле Запрос <-> Ответ.
2. Общение в стиле Запрос <-> Ответ и возможность получения данных по событию оборудования.

Как правильно реализовать логику общения через асинхронность? Я написал два варианта для реализации, но ни один мне не нравится.
Вариант 1 через ManualResetEvent:

```
public class TestSerialPortV1
{
    private enum AnswerType
    {
        Executed,
        Busy,
        HardwareError,
        Disconnected,
        InterferenceInLine,
    }
    // Мой класс, для возвращения ответа потоку, запросившему инфу.
    private class HybridMRE<TResult>
    {
        private int _isReset;
        private ManualResetEvent _mre;
        private TResult _result;

        public bool IsReset
        {
            get { return _isReset == 1; }
        }

        public HybridMRE()
        {
            _isReset = 0;
            _mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isReset, 1, 0) == 0)
                _mre.Reset();
        }
        public void Set(TResult result)
        {
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isReset, 0, 1) == 0)
            {
                _result = result;
                _mre.Set();
            }
        }

        public bool Wait(out TResult result)
        {
            if (_isReset == 1)
            {
                var resultOfWait = _mre.WaitOne();
                result = _result;
                return resultOfWait;
            }
            result = default(TResult);
            return true;
        }
        public bool Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, out TResult result)
        {
            if (_isReset == 1)
            {
                var resultOfWait = _mre.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout);
                result = _result;
                return resultOfWait;
            }
            result = default(TResult);
            return true;
        }
        public bool Wait(TimeSpan timeout, out TResult result)
        {
            if (_isReset == 1)
            {
                var resultOfWait = _mre.WaitOne(timeout);
                result = _result;
                return resultOfWait;
            }
            result = default(TResult);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private SerialPort _port;

    // Буфер для хранения информации.
    private byte[] _bytesForBuffer;
    private int _inIndex;
    private int _outIndex;

    private HybridMRE<AnswerType> _mreForCommand1;

    public TestSerialPortV1()
    {
        _port = new SerialPort("COM1");
        _port.Open();

        _bytesForBuffer = new byte[200];
        _inIndex = 0;
        _outIndex = 0;

        _mreForCommand1 = new HybridMRE<AnswerType>();
    }

    private async Task ReceiveData()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                _outIndex += await _port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(_bytesForBuffer, _outIndex, _bytesForBuffer.Length - _outIndex);

                // Логика проверки на наличие целого ответа, иначе читаем далее.

                if (_mreForCommand1.IsReset)
                {
                    // Проверяем полученный ответ.
                    AnswerType answer = TestAnswerForCommand1();
                    _mreForCommand1.Set(answer);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException) { }
    }

    private AnswerType TestAnswerForCommand1()
    {
        // Некая работа.
        return AnswerType.InterferenceInLine;
    }
    public async Task<bool> ExecuteComman1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            _mreForCommand1.Reset();
            byte[] command1 = new byte[5];
            command1[0] = 0x5A;
            command1[2] = 0x3;
            await _port.BaseStream.WriteAsync(command1, 0, 5);
            AnswerType answer;
            if (_mreForCommand1.Wait(1000, out answer))
            {
                switch(answer)
                {
                    case AnswerType.Executed:
                        return true;
                    case AnswerType.Busy:
                    case AnswerType.HardwareError:
                        return false;
                    case AnswerType.InterferenceInLine:
                        continue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                answer = AnswerType.Disconnected;
                continue;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Пример 2 через Task<>:

```
public class TestSerialPortV2
{
    private enum AnswerType
    {
        Executed,
        Busy,
        HardwareError,
        Disconnected,
        InterferenceInLine,
    }

    private SerialPort _port;

    private byte[] _bytesForBuffer;
    private int _inIndex;
    private int _outIndex;

    private Task<AnswerType> _taskForCommand1;

    public TestSerialPortV2()
    {
        _port = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200);
        _port.Open();

        _bytesForBuffer = new byte[200];
        _inIndex = 0;
        _outIndex = 0;

        _taskForCommand1 = Task.FromResult(AnswerType.Executed);

        var task = ReceiveData();
    }

    private async Task ReceiveData()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int readedbytes = await _port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(_bytesForBuffer, _outIndex, _bytesForBuffer.Length - _outIndex);
                _outIndex += readedbytes;

                // Логика проверки на наличие целого ответа, иначе читаем далее.

                if (_taskForCommand1.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
                {
                    // Проверяем полученный ответ.
                    _taskForCommand1.Start();
                    await _taskForCommand1;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Read something " + readedbytes);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException) { }
    }

    private AnswerType TestAnswerForCommand1()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine("CalculatingBytes");
        // Некая работа.
        return AnswerType.InterferenceInLine;
    }

    public async Task<bool> ExecuteComman1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _taskForCommand1 = new Task<AnswerType>(TestAnswerForCommand1, cts.Token);
            byte[] command1 = new byte[5];
            command1[0] = 0x5A;
            command1[2] = 0x3;

            await _port.BaseStream.WriteAsync(command1, 0, 5);
            //await _port.BaseStream.FlushAsync();

            cts.CancelAfter(10000);
            AnswerType answer;
            try
            {
                answer = await _taskForCommand1;
                switch (answer)
                {
                    case AnswerType.Executed:
                        return true;
                    case AnswerType.Busy:
                    case AnswerType.HardwareError:
                        return false;
                    case AnswerType.InterferenceInLine:
                        continue;
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                answer = AnswerType.Disconnected;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что должно происходить в ситуации, когда вы послали запрос, и тем временем пришло событие от оборудования? Как можно понять, пришедшие после этого данные — это ответ на запрос или данные к событию?

Comment: @VladD Маркерные байты, количество информационных байт между маркерными байтами, код ответа, что находится внутри информационных байт. В общем эта вещь предусмотрена и уже написана. Проблема как лучше архитектуру построить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я недавно реализовывал нечто подобное, у меня получилось следующее:

1. Всё реализовано асинхронно, через `async`/`await`.
2. Запускается читающая процедура, которая в цикле читает из потока данные, передаёт их парсеру, который делит их на сообщения, и отправляет event с пришедшим сообщением:

   ```
   async Task Reader(Stream s, CancellationToken ct)
   {
       try
       {
           while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
           {
               var messageSizeBytes = await ReadAsync(stream, 4, ct);
               var messageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(messageSizeBytes);
               var messageRest = await ReadAsync(stream, messageSize, ct);
               var inMessage = Parser.Parse(messageRest);
               OnNewMessage(inMessage);
           }
       }
       catch (OperationCancelledException)
       {
           Tracer.Message("Reader stopped");
       }
       catch (<обработайте остальные исключения>)
       {
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. Процедура отсылки сообщения:

   ```
   async Task SendMessage(Stream s, OutMessage message, CancellationToken ct)
   {
       var messageBytes = message.serialize();
       await StreamHelper.SendAsync(s, messageBytes, ct);
   }
   ```
4. Процедура отсылки сообщения и ожидания ответа. Она требует фильтрации ответов, т. к. могут случайно прийти другие данные.

   ```
   async Task<InMessage> SendAndRecieve(
           OutMessage req, Stream s,
           Func<InMessage, bool> filter, CancellationToken ct)
   {
       var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<InMessage>();
       InMessageHandler handler = msg => { if (filter(msg)) tcs.TrySetResult(msg); };
       IncomingMessage += handler;
       try
       {
           await SendMessage(s, req, ct);
           using (ct.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled()))
               return await tcs.Task;
       }
       finally
       {
           IncomingMessage -= handler;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Теперь клиенты могут посылать сообщения и принимать ответы, используя `SendAndRecieve`. Для принятия out-of-bound-сообщений нужно подписаться на `IncomingMessage`.

Возможно, красивее было бы вместо события `IncomingMessage` применить Rx extensions и перейти на `IObservable<InMessage>`.

Кажется, всё.

---

**Дополнение**:

Как верно замечает @Pavel Mayorov, функция `filter` должна быть готова к тому, что её фактически вызовут и после окончания отработки `SendAndReceive`. Это обусловлено общей проблемой с многопоточными событиями: пока вы отписываетесь в одном потоке, другой поток может отправить ещё одно или даже несколько событий.

Если вы не можете такого обеспечить, в качестве альтернативы можно просто заставить `OnNewMessage` работать в том же потоке, что и клиентский код. Но это всё же не самое чистое решение.

Comment: Маленькая деталь: в такой схеме существует шанс, что `filter` будет вызван уже после завершения `SendAndRecieve` - и, таким образом, будет исполняться параллельно с продолжением вызывающей функции. Это может оказаться нехорошим сюрпризом.

Comment: В случае, когда при выходе из функции фильтр как раз выполняется, надо как-нибудь дождаться завершения его выполнения.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Вроде бы нет, мы отписываемся от `IncomingMessage` перед выходом. Обратите внимание, что я пишу не `return tcs.Task`, а `return await tcs.Task;`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Если `filter` ещё не вернул `true`, то мы не выходим и всё в порядке. Если `filter` уже раньше вернул `true`, то даже если функция `filter` выполнится после выхода и снова вернёт `true`, `TrySetResult` не повлияет ни на что.

Comment: событие может уже начать обрабатываться в момент отписывания. Впрочем, глянул еще раз ваш код - все зависит от реализации `OnNewMessage`. Если там событие вызывается синхронно - то и правда ничего страшного.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Но да, функция `filter` должна быть готова к тому, что её вызовут после окончания работы `SendAndReceive`. То есть по сути она должна бы быть pure-функцией и не зависеть от внешнего мира.

Comment: *"Но да, функция `filter` должна быть готова к тому, что её вызовут позже."* - это очень неочевидно. Причем, если функция к этому "не готова" - выпавшее исключение может и вовсе остановить задачу чтения данных. Такую ошибку можно потом месяцами искать...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, необходимости логгинга ошибок никто не отменял. Хотя да, напишу пояснение, спасибо!

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Дописал.

Comment: @ilivit В общем по твоему ответу и ответу ilivit я понял, что мне лучше взять свой второй вариант с `Task` и использовать вместо него `TaskComplitionSource`. Ранее не знал, как связать его и токен отмены, теперь знаю :-) Конкретно твой пример мне не подойдет из-за протокола оборудования.

Comment: @Nodon а что не так с протоколом оборудования? Этот пример можно использовать с любым протоколом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Можно воспользоваться, но часть вещей можно упростить. У меня сейчас оборудование, без команды извне ничего отправлять не будет. Потому событие мне не нужно. В ответе я получаю только маркер конца сообщения, при получении которого уже можно запустить код проверки напрямую без события. И мы приходим к тому, что я написал у себя в втором варианте, но на Task, а не TCS.

Comment: @Nodon: Можно — не значит нужно. Событие в моей архитектуре служит для уменьшения связности: чтобы обрабатывающий код был отделён от читающего кода.

Comment: @VladD Сидел тут копался. Несколько раз переписывал код, в итоге пришел к тому варианту, как у тебя. С небольшими отличиями только.

Answer (score 3):

В SerialPort есть событие DataReceived, которое возникает при появлении данных из последовательного порта. При реализации асинхронного общения с портом во 2 варианте (Task) можно использовать [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd449174) и [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx). Порядок работы следующий:

1. При отправке запроса в порт создается TaskCompletionSource и CancellationTokenSource
2. Для CancellationTokenSource через Token.Register() добавляется обработчик отмены и выставляется таймаут.
3. Данные записываются в порт.
4. Ожидается завершение задачи через await для TaskCompletionSource.
5. При приходе данных с порта пытаемся их обработать.
6. В случае успеха завершаем задачу через TaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult()
7. В случае ошибки завершаем задачу через TaskCompletionSource.TrySetException()
8. В случае таймаута сработает обаботчик CancellationTokenSource.

Пример класса с реализацией вышеописанного поведения:

```
class ModemConnection : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SerialPort _serialPort;
    private bool _disposed;

    private TaskCompletionSource<Frame> _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Frame>();

    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }

    public ModemConnection(string portName, int baudRate, Parity parity, int dataBits, StopBits stopBits)
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits);
        _serialPort.DataReceived += _serialPort_DataReceived;

    }

    private async Task<Frame> SendFrame(Frame frame)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Frame>();
        cts.Token.Register(tcs => ((TaskCompletionSource<Frame>)tcs).TrySetCanceled(), _taskCompletionSource, false);
        cts.CancelAfter(Timeout);

        var bw = new BinaryWriter(_serialPort.BaseStream, Encoding.ASCII, true);
        frame.Write(bw);
        bw.Flush();
        Task.Run(() => OnOnFrameSent(frame));

        return await _taskCompletionSource.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var r = new BinaryReader(new BufferedStream(_serialPort.BaseStream), Encoding.ASCII, true);
            var frame = new Frame();
            frame.Read(r);
            _taskCompletionSource?.TrySetResult(frame);

            Task.Run(() => OnOnFrameReceived(frame));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _taskCompletionSource?.TrySetException(ex);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<Frame> FrameReceived;

    protected virtual void OnOnFrameReceived(Frame e)
    {
        FrameReceived?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    public event EventHandler<Frame> FrameSent;

    protected virtual void OnOnFrameSent(Frame e)
    {
        FrameSent?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        if (_serialPort.IsOpen) return;
        _serialPort.Open();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        _disposed = true;
        _serialPort.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: В методе `SendFrame` можно возвращать задачу напрямую, `async/await` тут и не требуется. Методы `OnOnFrameReceived` и `OnOnFrameSent` попросту опасны - из-за гонок они могут быть вызваны совсем не в том порядке, в котором их ждали. Возможно, лучше было бы вызывать их синхронно.

Comment: Ну и `_taskCompletionSource` лучше бы все-таки объявить `volatile`, чтобы его не "съел" оптимизатор.

Comment: `DataReceived` использовать не рекомендуется. Вот прочти это. http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Comment: @PavelMayorov А с чего это компилятор может решить оптимизировать `_taskCompletionSource`?

Comment: @Nodon да мало ли...